# Completely disable logs from XCGLogger when in production

Tags: ios, swift, logging, xcglogger

How do I completely disable logs from XCGLogger when in production environment?

At present I am using `logLevel = .None`.

Is this the recommended way ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's one possible way, but not ideal.

First, I'd wonder if you really want to completely disable logs in production. using `error` and `severe` logs can be useful diagnostic tools for released apps.

If you do however want to completely eliminate logs in production, I would recommend altering the way you set up and use the logger than what I have in the official docs.

Change the global log object to be an optional instead:

```
let log: XCGLogger? = {
    #if DEBUG
        let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()
        log.setup(.Debug, showThreadName: true, showLogLevel: true, showFileNames: true, showLineNumbers: true, writeToFile: nil, fileLogLevel: .Debug)
        return log
    #else
        return nil
    #endif
}
```

Then change your log calls to:

```
log?.debug("whatever")
```

This will eliminate any overhead of the logger since `log` will be `nil` in production and no logging calls will ever be made.

Comment: Btw. How can the severe and error logs in production reach back to me if I do not completely remove them

Comment: With the current version, you'd need to talk to the user having the issue and they may be able to see them in their console log. Or you add a method to have the app email you the log file, or even report it to a remote server. I plan to add some remote reporting stuff by the end of the year (if time permits).